# How to solve Application package com.google.android.backup not found?

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add Firebase authentication and Facebook login on my Android application. I added these dependencies on my app and when I tried to start my app, it shows this error:

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
```

From the error itself, the `com.google.android.backup is missing`, but how do I add this package? What does this package do?

app.gradle (added the following)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

//Firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'

//Facebook SDK
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

project.gradle

```
mavenCentral() //added on the repositories section

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: Are you sure that error is actually related to your app? In the manifest you can disable app backups

Comment: Also, firebase latest version is `10.2.0`

Comment: I was already able to fix this by updating Google Repository and Google Play Services

Comment: @zbryan, which means your question is no longer actual. Either answer yourself or remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Repository and Google Play Service should be updated on its latest version. You can update these on your Android studio's SDK manager.